# search by value which starts with certain string in nested JSON

Tags: javascript, json, object

Example Nested JSON

```
    {
          "a": "https://example1.com",
          "b": {
            "c":"https://example2.com",
            "d": {
              "e": "www.example3.com"
            }
          },
         "f": {
            "g":"https://example4.com"
          }

        }
      }
```

Want to filter the values starting with only 'http'. Unable to find any example for nested json.

(optional)Is there a way to achive this in object-scan npm

Expected result

```
['https://example1.com', 'https://example2.com', 'https://example4.com']
```

Comment: Loop the keys, check the value for the type, if string, parse beginning, else, loop inner object... etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop keys, check the type, repeat as needed:

```
function loopAndParse(thing, rtn) {
    Object.keys(thing).forEach(k => {
        if (typeof thing[k] === "string" && thing[k].indexOf("https://") > -1) 
            rtn.push(thing[k])
        else if (typeof thing[k] === "object") return loopAndParse(thing[k], rtn)
    })
    return rtn;
}

console.log(loopAndParse(obj, []))
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7megL295/

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you would solve this using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) (as asked in the question)

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const data = { a: 'https://example1.com', b: { c: 'https://example2.com', d: { e: 'www.example3.com' } }, f: { g: 'https://example4.com' } };

console.log(objectScan(['**'], {
  reverse: false,
  filterFn: ({ value }) => typeof value === 'string' && value.startsWith('http'),
  rtn: 'value'
})(data));
// => [ 'https://example1.com', 'https://example2.com', 'https://example4.com' ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@14.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Comment: This library is great. Could you @vincent elaborate such examples on your github readme? Currently, such helpful examples are scattered around on stackoverflow.

Comment: Good idea. There are lots of examples in the readme, but I should include more involved ones as well.

Answer (score 0):

Extract values recursively, flat the array, filter the array by `https`

```js
const foo = {
  "a": "https://example1.com",
  "b": {
    "c": "https://example2.com",
    "d": {
      "e": "www.example3.com"
    }
  },
  "f": {
    "g": "https://example4.com"
  }

}


function extractValues(data) {
  const run = data => {
    return Object.values(data).map(value => {
      if (typeof value === 'object') {
        return extractValues(value)
      } else {
        return value
      }
    })
  }
  return run(data).flat(Infinity)
}

let a = extractValues(foo).filter(url => /^https/.test(url))

console.log(a)
```